# How to remove abrasion fog from tempered glass?

Tags: cleaning, water, glass

When you use abrasives or acids on tempered glass, it can sometimes (contrary to normal glass) develop a fog or haze. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: This sounds like one for https://crafts.stackexchange.com/ but I'd check their tour first.

Comment: this is duplicate ; please search your answer before asking. [Check this link please](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/any-idea-how-to-remove-this-build-up-from-glass-shower-door/15422#15422)

Comment: @melic I'm afraid it's not a duplicate and my problem is quite different. The question you linked to was concerned with some kind of deposit, not so in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regrettably, tempered glass is **very** sensitive to any scratch or abrasion. The surface is under great stress, and a scratch can quickly propagate, causing the entire piece of glass to shatter into numerous little cubes.

There are some [suggestions for polishing the glass](http://www.ehow.com/how_5529419_remove-scratches-tempered-glass.html), but realize that the glass is already compromised and might shatter during polishing.

If you cannot replace the glass, a temporary way to make it look better would be to cover the scratches with clear plastic spray. Unless you can find a product with the same index of refraction as the glass, though, it will not hide the abrasion completely.